# Displaying a loading GIF inside a button click and hiding it again once the action is performed

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have the following JFrame with a simple enough exit application method inside. I am trying to add a loader of some sort (preferably a spinner GIF). However, at the moment I have just added a JLabel called loading to display the text "loading..." on button click.

The issue is that the messagebox (i.e. the action) is not shown at all in my function and the loading JLabel continues to display. Could anyone explain why this isn't working and give me suggestions as to how to replace the loading text with a GIF. Any help would be great.

```
 public void Exit() {
    btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // event start
            loading.setVisible(true);

            new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    // event start
                    loading.setVisible(false);

                    // prompt user input message box //
                    int close = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(panel,"Are you sure?",
                            "Information", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                    // await user selection.
                    if(close == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the `SwingWorker` is not enough by itself. You must call its [execute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute()) method after you created it.

> Schedules this SwingWorker for execution on a worker thread. There are
>   a number of worker threads available. In the event all worker threads
>   are busy handling other SwingWorkers this SwingWorker is placed in a
>   waiting queue.
>
> Note: SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once. Executing a
>   SwingWorker more than once will not result in invoking the
>   doInBackground method twice.

In your case:

```
SwingWorker<?,?> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // event start
        loading.setVisible(false);

        // prompt user input message box //
        int close = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(panel,"Are you sure?",
                "Information", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        // await user selection.
        if(close == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
};
worker.execute(); //Execute the worker
```

Comment: This makes sense now! Thanks for all your help!